# Application permissions for Standard user

Tags: macos, applications, permission, user-account

I use my Mac as a Standard user. When I first set it up, all applications were downloaded/installed using the Admin user. Running latest OSX 10.10.3

When using my Mac as the Standard user, every time I go to run an application I get the following message:

```
"Whatever.app" is an application downloaded from the Internet.
Are you sure you want to open it?
```

With the options for `Cancel` and `Open`. Of course I choose `Open` and everything works fine.

Now, I am used to this notice appearing the *first* time I try to run an app from the internet. My problem is that it appears *every* time.

Note that I am not asked for any Administrator credentials, and these apps have already been installed to the `/Applications` directory as an Administrator.

I have tried with a different Standard user and still have the same issue. I have also already used Disk Utility to repair the drive permissions, just in case.

How can I make this notice appear only on the first run?

==========================================================

I found another "clue". If I install an application, *while logged in as the Standard user, but authenticating as the Administrator,* then it only warns me about the Application on the first run, and then never again, *as long as I am still logged in as that Standard user.*

But all the applications I installed *while logged in as Administrator* give me a pop up warning *every time* if I try to run them *while logged in as a Standard user.* There must be a way to fix this.

==========================================================

**UPDATE**

**"Solution"**: For every application I downloaded and installed, while logged in as Administrator, simply installing the application is not enough. I must actually login as the Administrator and launch the application at least once to clear the warning for all other users. This seems incredible silly. I'm glad I found a "fix", but surely there must be a better way to accomplish this?

Comment: Is this before or after reset ACLs?

Comment: OS X uses the com.apple.quarantine attribute on the application bundle, as well as the database entries stored in "~/Library/Preferences/com.apple.LaunchServices.QuarantineEventsV2" to determine whether or not to show that message. You can try running `sqlite3 ~/Library/Preferences/com.apple.LaunchServices.QuarantineEventsV2 .dump|grep -i LibreOffice` replacing LibreOffice with whichever application is exhibiting this issue, and see if you get any results. If not, then it's possible there's an issue with this database.

Comment: If you do get a result, post them here along with the result of `xattr -p com.apple.quarantine /Applications/LibreOffice.app`, or compare them yourself, again, replacing LibreOffice with the name of an application exhibiting this. The first value in the database record should match the last value in the extended attribute.

Comment: I used VLC as an example.

`sqlite3 ~/Library/Preferences/com.apple.LaunchServices.QuarantineEventsV2 .dump|grep -i VLC`

No result.

Comment: I also reset the user permissions and ACLs before this.

Comment: I think I found a "solution", but it is ***incredibly inelegant***. There must be a better way to accomplish this in OS X. If I login, as Administrator, then launch an app, it will give me the standard warning with `Cancel` and `Open` (`Show Webpage` is also an option). If I choose `Open` then all subsequent launches do not display any warning. Now if I login as the Standard user, no more warnings display when I try to open that specific application.

Comment: In other words, for every application I downloaded and installed as Administrator, simply installing the Application is not enough. I must actually login as the Administrator and launch the application at least once to clear the warning for all other users. This seems incredible silly. I'm glad I found a "fix", but surely there must be a better way to accomplish this?