# Remove SKYPE HELPER popup easy way Mac OS X

Tags: skype

I found this and tested it on MacBook. No need to open the terminal. Just do it before the Skype update to be installed.

- Go to Skype prefs and check for Update.
- If it is available, the popup window for Skype Helper will show up. IGNORE IT FOR NOW.
- Go to ˇAbout Skypeˇ and when it opens THEN go to the popup and authenticate it.
  The green or blue button will be visible on Skype window for update.
  – Click on it. Done.
- If it asks you again for authentication, it is normal.

Comment: This seems to be a duplicate of the accepted answer at  [annoyance: latest version of Skype under Standard (non-admin) user on macOS 10.13](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/335863/annoyance-latest-version-of-skype-under-standard-non-admin-user-on-macos-10-1)

Comment: You’re welcome to ask and answer your own question, but put the answer in the answer box and leave the question as a question. This helps other people find the problem and see that it has a solution, as well as allowing others to provide an alternative solution.