# How to stop gatekeeper always asking for app verification in standard account?

Tags: permission, gatekeeper

I've recently done a clean install of High Sierra and am struggling with reducing the annoyance of the app verification from gatekeeper. For security I log in as a standard user and have a separate admin account - this is the first time I've tried that separation between admin and standard accounts, which is where the problem may lie.

If I right-click the app and 'open', then confirm open again in the gatekeeper dialog, then I will still be asked every time I open the app.

I have disabled gatekeeper (security pane now has third radio button - allowing 'Anywhere' for download source) but this hasn't helped.

I used `brew cask` to download and install a number of apps and suspect it's those that I can't permanently approve.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how to avoid the “downloaded application” warning for a Standard User](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/329603/how-to-avoid-the-downloaded-application-warning-for-a-standard-user).

Answer (score 1):

you can try this in terminal To add an application to Gatekeepers exceptions and approved application launch list,

```
spctl --add /Path/To/Application.app
```

replace the Path and Application with yours

Comment: Doesn't work ... it gives a permission dialog for the admin user (which I put in), but on next launch it still gets Gatekeeper notice.

Comment: interesting,  maybe it needs a Restart after issuing the command to To add an application to Gatekeepers exceptions and approved application launch list, to become permanent.